# Serializing a textbox in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, textbox, invalidoperationexception

I am a beginner with .NET environment.
I have a windows application with three textboxes and one button. When the user clicks on the button, i want all the textbox values to be serialized in an XML format to a file. 
I tried doing it this way,

```
    DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddCustomer customer = new AddCustomer();
        customer.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
        customer.textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text;
        customer.textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text;
        customer.textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text;

            saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"D:";
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Xml Files | *.xml";
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog().Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {

                SerializeToXML(customer);
            }            
    }

    public void SerializeToXML(AddCustomer customer)
    {

           XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddCustomer));
            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\customer.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, customer);
            textWriter.Close();
    }
```

this returned system.invalidoperationexception was unhandled exception

any ideas? 
Thanks,
Michael

Comment: What is AddCustomer? Is it a Form? Why can't you create a class with four string properties and then serialize that, instead of the current implementation.

Comment: The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state.

Comment: yes, it's a form with 4 textboxes and i need to serialize the values the user puts in them to an xml file.

Comment: Exactly which line is throwing the error (preferably on the code as per @AVD's answer...)

Comment: XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AddCustomer));             ..that's the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to write XML in .NET.  Here is a way using [`XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) that works for very simple content like in this case:

```
string text1 = /* get value of textbox */;
string text2 = /* get value of textbox */;
string text3 = /* get value of textbox */;

// Set indent=true so resulting file is more 'human-readable'
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true };

// Put writer in using scope; after end of scope, file is automatically saved.
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create("file.xml", settings))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("root");
    writer.WriteElementString("text1", text1);
    writer.WriteElementString("text2", text2);
    writer.WriteElementString("text3", text3);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

One note: you should avoid doing file operations on the UI thread as this can result in blocking behavior (e.g. the disk can be slow and cause the UI to freeze up while it writes the file, or it could be writing to a network location and hang for a while as it connects).  It is best to put up a progress dialog and display a message "Please wait while file is saved..." and do the file operation in the background; a simple way is to post the background operation the thread pool [using `BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx).

---

If you want to use the XmlSerializer instead, then you would follow these steps:

1. Create a `public` type to act as the root element of your document and mark it with [`XmlRoot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx).
2. Add elements/attributes made of either primitive/built-in types or your own `public` custom types which are also XML serializable, marking them with [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) or [`XmlAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx) as necessary.
3. To write the data out, use [`XmlSerializer.Serialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize.aspx) with an appropriate `Stream`, `StreamWriter`, or `XmlWriter` along with your root object.
4. To read the data back in, use [`XmlSerializer.Deseralize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize.aspx) with an appropriate `Stream`, `TextReader`, or `XmlReader`, casting the return type back to your root object.

**Full sample.**

The type to serialize:

```
[XmlRoot("customer")]
public class CustomerData
{
    // Must have a parameterless public constructor
    public CustomerData()
    {
    }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return
            "Name=[" + this.Name + "] " +
            "City=[" + this.City + "] " +
            "Company=[" + this.Company + "]";
    }
}
```

The code to read/write the data:

```
// Initialize the serializer to write and read the data
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomerData));

// Initialize the data to serialize
CustomerData dataToWrite = new CustomerData()
{
    Name = "Joel Spolsky",
    City = "New York",
    Company = "Fog Creek Software"
};

// Write it out
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true };
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create("customer.xml", settings))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, dataToWrite);
}

// Read it back in
CustomerData dataFromFile = null;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlTextReader.Create("customer.xml"))
{
    dataFromFile = (CustomerData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}

Console.WriteLine(dataFromFile);
```

Comment: out of curiosity, would u know how i could do it using serialization?

Answer (score 1):

You can't serialize controls instead you have to create `Serializable` component that represent TextBox values. (For more detail read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx) article).

For instance,

```
[Serializable]
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I just tried that one........and on the "button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)" I created an object of the customer class called customer1, then assigned Name=textbox1.Text;..and so on.....Still the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't serialize the textbox object, only their values.
`customer.textBox1` should be `customer.text1` of type string. You then need to just assign `customer.text1 = textbox1.text`.
Also, mark your `AddCustomer` class with the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Edit: This is a code I just tried and it works fine. See if you can make it work in your solution.

Add new class `Customer`

```
[Serializable]
public class Customer
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Try to serialize it like this

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.FullName = "John"; // or customer.FullName = textBox1.Text
customer.Age = "21"; // or customer.Age = textBox2.Text

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer));
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\customer.xml");
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, customer);
textWriter.Close();
```

After doing this, I got an xml file created with the following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customer xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <FullName>John</FullName>
  <Age>21</Age>
</Customer>
```

Try and compare to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: yes, this one works fine, because it's a console application. but i don't know how to implement it to windows application with more than one textbox and a button. .......that's the problem i'm having

Comment: Well, you will need to go through some tutorials on how to perform basic tasks with windows forms or wpf.